# how to select only a column having dates from a library using dictionary.columns

Tags: sas

```
  data dtetst;
        set date(keep= dtevar);
        dtevar=year(dtevar);
    run;
```

Hello am extracting & displaying year from an entire date this scenario i have achieved-> the above code works fine for extracting year from the dates

but am having another scenario to locate only those columns from a library having date datatype i.e select only those columns containing dates in them for example --> `mdtc 2012-10-16, 2014-06-15, 2000-08-14 ,2007-12-28`

i tried below code-->

```
 PROC SQL noprint;
     select distinct catx(".",libname,memname) into :list separated by " "
     from dictionary.columns
     where libname = upcase("dte") and format in('YYMMDD10.');
quit;

        %put &list;

        data tst3;
        set &list;
        date=year(mdtc);
        run;
```

I have updated my code it selects the columns with the specific format 
but the year function i use on date column to extract year from the dates it does not do intended action, of extracting the year from the date as shown below.

```
input data->  mdtc 2012-10-16, 2014-06-15, 2000-08-14 ,2007-12-28
```

desired output after using year function on column mdtc->

```
 mdtc 
 2012
 2014
 2000
 2007
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: This may help you get started. https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Determine-if-a-variable-contains-a-SAS-date-value/m-p/154851/highlight/true#M30347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to reliably detect a 'date' datatype in a SAS table, as all dates / datetimes are stored as simple numerics (you can only have numeric and character datatypes in SAS).  A SAS date is simply the number of days since 01JAN1960.

However - you can detect those columns that have a date FORMAT applied, which would reasonably indicate a date column, eg as follows:

```
proc sql;
create table example as select * 
  from dictionary.columns 
  where libname='SASHELP'
  and format in ('DATE9.','DATE7.');
```

The drawback with this approach is that you need to explicitly list every date format used.  Also, it relies on date formats being applied.  It also presumes we are talking about numeric dates (no way to detect dates stored as character strings, which sometimes happens).

Comment: You could obviously make use of the % wildcard operator, in conjunction with `like`, to make searching easier, e.g. DATE%, DD%, MM%, MON%, DT%.  This assumes that the OP doesn't need to differentiate between dates and datetimes

Comment: @user7108488 - this is not how stackoverflow should work!  I answered your question, so my answer should have been accepted, and your new question about how the year function works should be a new question.

Comment: But in any case, the reason is that you are re-using the column with the format applied, so you are getting the date which corresponds to value of the year - eg 2012 days since 01JAN1960.

Comment: I see you have changed the question again, so that you are creating a new column (date) from the mdtc column.  Does `date` have a date format?  If so try either `format date 8.;` or put your year in a new variable, eg `year=year(mdtc)`.

Comment: If the above does not fix the issue, I'd wager that mdtc is not a date column.  Do you get warnings / errors in the log?  What results DO you get?